# Stack Overflow CSS doesn't load

Tags: support, mobile-web, google-chrome

I'm using Stack Overflow on my Samsung Galaxy Duos S7562, and when I tried to load the page in the Google Chrome mobile app, it didn't look right:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's usually a network error that prevented the CSS from downloading. Try refreshing.

Comment: Whenever you get an unstyled page like this, try a hard refresh.

Comment: @JanDvorak Posted an answer a second after you :)

Comment: @ColeJohnson I already tried refreshing it, might be some problem in wifi.  Let me check and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That issue would be caused by a network issue preventing the CSS and images from downloading. It can happen whereever there is a weak connection. It can happen on desktop computers also. A simple refresh should fix it. If it doesn't, try again somewhere else.

This could be an issue of your ISP blocking `cdn.sstatic.net`. If that is the case, try contacting them and asking them to unblock it. In either case, as I said above, try it again using a different network; i.e. try 3G instead of Wi-Fi.

Comment: Gotcha! the problem was with the wifi, looking great (I am using mobile data).  This is my 1st comment,vote and selecting answer via mobile phone :) Thanks

Comment: Any reason for removing my request upon App notification in login screen?

Comment: @Praveen it's a different question. If you read my comment in the edit, it says "removing unrelated stuff"

Comment: Oh, okay.  I checked a question, currently they are working of official app which is in alpha testing stage.  I have requested for SE App(eager to use), once I get I will let community about my thoughts :) thank you.